# AngularJS - similar page structure with different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, url-routing

I have template page with ng-repeat on it. But I want to have 2 pages with similar structure and different data on it. Is it possible to do it in AngularJS? To switch between pages I'm using angular's routing - so maybe there is a way to get data through URL params? Or maybe more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example see 2 routes that use the same template but have different controllers and different urls:

```
.state('edit-workhours', {
    url: "/workhours/edit/:scheduler_id/:calander_id",
    templateUrl: 'partials/edit-workhour.html',
    controller: 'EditWorkhoursController'
})
.state('add-workhours', {
    url: "/workhours/add/:scheduler_id/:calander_id",
    templateUrl: 'partials/edit-workhour.html',
    controller: 'AddWorkhoursController'
})
```

as you can see **edit-workhour.html** is common between the 2 routes

if you want the same controller:

```
.state('A', {
    url: "/routeA",
    templateUrl: 'partials/partialA.html',
    controller: 'ControllerA'
})
.state('B', {
    url: "/routeB",
    templateUrl: 'partials/partialA.html',
    controller: 'ControllerA'
})
```

Comment: But if I want to make it with one controller? Maybe some sort of checking routeParams? How to pass them?

Comment: you can change the name of the controller so it will be the same controller but 2 different routes

Comment: Ok, got it. But how html-page will looks like with this routing? href=":params" ?

Comment: you can define the routing you want it, if you want to add params just addd /routeA/:param1/:param2, routeB can be the same or different, please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I mean, how my link will looks like in html page to pass params? <a href="/routeA/:params">link</a> Something like this?